# Server Side Swift Using Kitura Framework

Tags: server-side-swift

i hope all is well

i start learning the server side swift before one week and i face the problem and no one tell me how can i fix it till this day

the problem is when i use the StencilTemplateEngine with upToNextMinor(from: "1.8.5" nthe tags not working which i use it with the html for the stencil i save the file and i named it (staff.stencil) when i write tag stencil  in the file it's not working and give me cannot get name

the code below:

```
<html>

<head>
   <title>Staff Page</title>
</head>

<body>

     {% if name %}
     {{ name }}
     <br />
     { bio }
     {% else %}
    <p>we can't fetch this user</p>
</body>

</html>
```

in the browser i put the url : localhost:8080/staff/term

thanks a lot